# Windows 10 mobile persistent UDID

Tags: windows, windows-phone, windows-10, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-universal

I am currently working on a Windows 10 (mobile) app and I need a persistent UDID.

I was thinking about using **[ASHWID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj553431)** but that ID can change if the device has dockable elements such as a keyboard.

So I was wondering which other ID's could be used. (Hardware info such as CPU serial, ... would be even better).

Any ideas ?

*Side question about ASHWID: If I delete my app then reinstall it will the ASHWID still be the same ?*

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASHWID is definitely the way to go for UWP.
Using weight for sensible components, you can ensure that you can deal with hardware changes.

This sample might help you to deal with components
https://github.com/markmeeus/ASHWIDParser

App reinstallation does not affect the ASHWID.

Comment: So there is no way I can get Hardware info such as CPU serial or any other data that doesn't change at all ?

Comment: No, you have to rely on the HardwareIdentification APIs

Comment: Hmm yup seems so :). One last question then we're done :)
Does the ASHWID change when we disable something like the bluetooth ? It does on my windows 10 pc but am not sure about the phone. I haven't received my Windows Phone yet so can't check it by myself.

Comment: No it doesn't. It change when you change hardware components